# Php script for import configurable products from csv

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, configurable-product, import

I need to **import** a lot of **products**. So i want to use a **script**. So if you have any script to do that can you share the **whole php file**?

Comment: for what version of Magento? why not use the default product import functionality?

Comment: magento 2.2.7 . Scripts works faster that's why